# R Studio Convert .RMD to pdf

Tags: r

all
Ufff... I believe I did my hw to research this and still don't have an answer so asking all:
I have R-Studio, valid RMD file, when I tried to  I don't get new .pdf file, I have viewer which is still html.

No problem to create HTML, it works fine, but I need pdf.
tried to use render ("file.RMD", "file.PDF") to find that I don't have render, tried install pandoc, got an error <  package ‘pandoc’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)>

so what is the simple way to get that pdf, why my  doesn't work as desinged? what I'm missing I put that info into header too...
output: pdf_document

Im totaly lost, appreciate help.

```
render("Proj1.RMD", "Proj1.pdf")
```

Best
Mario

Comment: Further research showed that :  No TeX installation detected (TeX is required to create PDF output)   and then in turn I got that error trying to install Tex (MiKTex)    <br> > install.packages("MiKTeX")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/vmoshkovoy/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘MiKTeX’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: package ‘MiKTeX’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)    ??????? why

Comment: MiKTeX isn't an R package, and neither is Pandoc. See [here](http://rprogramming.net/create-html-or-pdf-files-with-r-knitr-miktex-and-pandoc/).

Comment: The usual workaround I've seen, if you don't want to bother with installing TeX, is to just render to HTML, and then save that web page to a pdf via your browser.